# How to fake an event in mootools?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mootools

Sample code:

```
<div id="first">first div</div>
<div id="second">second div, click here or on the previous it's the same</div>
```

Suppose I set an event onclick on the first div that alerts the div's content. 
How do I call that event? In example clicking on the second div I'd like it to call the click event of the first div and alert('first div')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out their [Element.fireEvent()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:fireEvent) method.  Try this:

```
$('first').addEvent('click', function()  { 
             alert($('first').innerHTML); 
});

$('second').addEvent('click', function()  { 
             $('first').fireEvent('click'); 
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

$('first').click();

Comment: this is not jquery and jquery is not javascript... sigh.

Comment: that is valid moo code and it is the simplest way to do it, IMO.

Comment: no it is not. you can use something like this:
Element.implement({'click': function(fn) { return this.addEvent('click',fn);} }); to mimic jquery's syntax but it certainly has not been a part of mootools core thus far...

Comment: oh - and this will just do the assignment and not the calling of the function - for that you need to fireEvent again :)

Comment: I think I need a vacation... I swear that was working in firebug yesterday.  I think I element.implemented it in my helpers somewhere.